# Mapping API with some Microservices with Ocelot duplicates controller name

Tags: asp.net-web-api, swagger, api-gateway, ocelot

i'm asking for help here because i'm trying to make an API Gateway with Ocelot and when I map the services with this

```
{
      "UpstreamPathTemplate": "/api/Product/{everything}",
      "UpstreamHttpMethod": [ "Post", "Get" ],

      "DownstreamScheme": "http",
      "DownstreamHostAndPorts": [
        {
          "Host": "localhost",
          "Port": 6666
        }
      ],
      "DownstreamPathTemplate": "/api/{everything}",
      "SwaggerKey": "product_api"
    }
```

And the controller starts with this

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class ProductController : Controller
    {
        IConfiguration _config;

        [NonAction]
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public ProductResponse GetProduct([FromQuery] int item_id, [FromHeader] string access_token)
```

Ocelot Swagger shows it like this
`/api/Product/Product/StoreStock`

With the "Product" duplicated, I guess it is because I map `api/Product/{everything}` and picks the Product from there and the Product from the controller name
But I can't use `api/{everything}` for every UpstreamPathTemplate because Ocelot doesn't let me do it.

Is there any way to fix the route or to map it to the `api/{controllername}` or something?

I tried mapping all to `api/{everything}` but Ocelot throw exception with that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is solved. I fixed it changing
`"DownstreamPathTemplate": "/api/{everything}"` to `"DownstreamPathTemplate": "/api/Product/{everything}"` and routes now are correct

Answer (score 0):

**DownstreamPathTemplate** contain destination path or api endpoint.

DownstreamPathTemplate sholud be change to api endpoint as follows

```
 "DownstreamPathTemplate": "/api/Product/{everything}"
```